# Risk of sql injection for custom search form

Tags: search, forms, sql

In my theme I have got a custom search form in header like this:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search..." />
<?php $query_types = get_query_var('post_type'); ?>         
    <div id="checkbox-wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" name="post_type[]" value="post" <?php if ( is_array($query_types) && in_array('post', $query_types)) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> /><label>Posts</label> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="post_type[]" value="custom_post_1" <?php if ( is_array($query_types) && in_array('custom_post_1', $query_types)) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> /><label>Custom post 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="post_type[]" value="custom_post_2" <?php if ( is_array($query_types) && in_array('custom_post_2', $query_types)) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> /><label>Custom post 2</label>           
        <input type="checkbox" name="post_type[]" value="custom_post_3" <?php if ( is_array($query_types) && in_array('custom_post_3', $query_types)) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> /><label>Custom post 3</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit-top-bar" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Just wanted to know wheter this code is written properly or could be sql injected.

Comment: Where's the other half of the code? The part that queries the database.

Comment: No other part of code in my theme's header seems to be related to this form, should I look somwhere else?

Comment: Somewhere there is code that takes what's entered in the form and does something with it, usually query the database, but it could do other stuff too. It's that code that you need to check for SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Since the form posts to your homepage (`home_url('/')`) - check `front-page.php` of your active theme, as well as `home.php` and `index.php`.

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing me to the right direction. Will check that.